# java web crawler

Tags: java

hi can anyone recommend a simple java web crawler that crawls a websites and return a list of links in the website ? No, i do not need a parser. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Ummm ... how does a web crawler extract the links in a web page without some kind of parser?

Answer (score 2):

A web crawler is (almost by definition) never 'simple'.

Two names spring to mind however (although both have a learning curve):

- [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org)
- [Heritrix](http://crawler.archive.org)

Both are open source and can accomplish what you want, although simply listing the links in a website is not what either is built for (Nutch is designed to build a search index and Heritrix is designed to archive websites). You will need to do some custom configurations to accomplish your task.

[HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) is a much simpler tool, but is not implemented in Java.